# Insert date from txt into database c#

Tags: c#

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("planificari.txt");
        string linie;
        while ((linie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] restr = { '*' };
            string[] txt = linie.Split(restr);
            foreach (var ser in txt) 
            {
                while (i < linie.Length-1)
                {
                    string ins = "insert into Planificari(Localitate,Frecventa,DataStart,DataStop,caleFisier)values('"+ser[i]+"','"+ser[i+1]+"','"+ser[i+2]+"','"+ser[i+3]+"','"+ser[i+4]+"')";
                    MessageBox.Show(ins);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ins, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                }
            }
```

Why i don t get the text word by word and i get char by char... ?
i have this text

```
Targu Neamt * ocazional * 02.05.2017 * 04.05.2017 * TarguNeamt1.jpg * TarguNeamt2.jpg * TarguNeamt3.jpg
Cluj-Napoca * ocazional * 10.05.2017 * 15.05.2017 * Cluj1.jpg * Cluj2.jpg * Cluj3.jpg * Cluj4.jpg
Ploiesti * ocazional * 18.05.2017 * 21.05.2017 * Ploiesti1.jpg * Ploiesti2.jpg * Ploiesti3.jpg * Ploiesti4.jpg
Sinaia * ocazional * 21.05.2017 * 23.05.2017 * Sinaia1.jpg * Sinaia2.jpg * Sinaia3.jpg
Constanta * ocazional * 12.06.2017 * 15.06.2017 * Constanta1.jpg * Constanta2.jpg * Constanta3.jpg * Constanta4.jpg
Mangalia * ocazional * 13.06.2018 * 18.06.2018 * Mangalia1.jpg * Mangalia2.jpg
Vatra Dornei * ocazional *  28.07.2019 * 05.08.2019 * VatraDornei1.jpg * VatraDornei2.jpg
Iasi * anual * 126 * Iasi1.jpg * Iasi2.jpg * Iasi3.jpg * Iasi4.jpg
Sibiu * anual * 132 * Sibiu1.jpg * Sibiu2.jpg * Sibiu3.jpg * Sibiu4.jpg
Predeal * anual * 171 * Predeal1.jpg * Predeal2.jpg * Predeal3.jpg
Barsana * lunar * 11 * Barsana1.jpg * Barsana2.jpg * Barsana3.jpg * Barsana4.jpg * Barsana5.jpg
Borsa * lunar * 22 * Borsa1.jpg *  Borsa2.jpg *  Borsa3.jpg * Borsa4.jpg
Brasov * lunar * 30 * Brasov1.jpg * Brasov2.jpg * Brasov3.jpg * Brasov4.jpg * Brasov5.jpg * Brasov6.jpg * Brasov7.jpg
```

and i get only this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMtWF.jpg

Comment: consider using a csv parser.

Comment: and you are introducing potential sql injection attacks!

Comment: You are looping on txt which is a string & represented as char array.

Comment: oh,ty  :) . @user1672994